# CDI injection of types in heirarchy

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf

I have a supertype (CaseDTO) with a couple subtypes (GroupCaseDTO, IPCaseDTO) that I want to inject. Dev environment is JDev 12c.

Here are the two injection points:

1. Injecting the supertype (this injection point works with both subtypes):

   @Inject @CaseContext
   private CaseDTO muwCase;
2. Inject a specific subtype (this injection point works with only one subtype):

   @Inject @CaseContext
   private GroupCaseDTO muwCase;

To get these values, I have tried to setup a number of producer methods:

```
// supertype
@Produces @CaseContext
public CaseDTO getContextCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", CaseDTO.class);
}

// subtype 1
@Produces @CaseContext
public IPCaseDTO getContextIpCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", IPCaseDTO.class);
}

// subtype 2
@Produces @CaseContext
public GroupCaseDTO getContextGroupCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", GroupCaseDTO.class);
}
```

The issue is, if I include only the supertype producer method, then the subtype injection point doesn't work:

```
:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type GroupCaseDTO with qualifiers @CaseContext
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @CaseContext private ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.decision.ManageGrpDecisionController.muwCase
at ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.decision.ManageGrpDecisionController.muwCase(ManageGrpDecisionController.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
- Managed Bean [class ca.bluecross.ab.muw.model.type.dto.grp.GroupCaseDTO] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

But if I include all three producer methods, I get this exception on the supertype injection point:

```
:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type CaseDTO with qualifiers @CaseContext
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @CaseContext private ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.UploadAssociatedDocumentController.muwCase
at ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.UploadAssociatedDocumentController.muwCase(UploadAssociatedDocumentController.java:0)
Possible dependencies: 
  - Producer Method [CaseDTO] with qualifiers [@CaseContext @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @CaseContext public ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.util.DataContextHelper.getContextCase()],
  - Producer Method [GroupCaseDTO] with qualifiers [@CaseContext @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @CaseContext public ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.util.DataContextHelper.getContextGroupCase()],
  - Producer Method [IPCaseDTO] with qualifiers [@CaseContext @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @CaseContext public ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.util.DataContextHelper.getContextIpCase()]
```

Having just the two subtype producer methods doesn't work either:

```
:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type CaseDTO with qualifiers @CaseContext
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @CaseContext private ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.UploadAssociatedDocumentController.muwCase
  at ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.controller.UploadAssociatedDocumentController.muwCase(UploadAssociatedDocumentController.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Producer Method [GroupCaseDTO] with qualifiers [@CaseContext @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @CaseContext public ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.util.DataContextHelper.getContextGroupCase()],
  - Producer Method [IPCaseDTO] with qualifiers [@CaseContext @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @CaseContext public ca.bluecross.ab.muw.view.util.DataContextHelper.getContextIpCase()]
```

I guess I can fix this by using a Qualifier annotation for each subtype that I need, but that seems excessive. Is there no way to get the injection working without a multitude of qualifier annotations?

In fact, here's what I want: one producer method + one qualifier annotation that allows me to inject the context case, regardless of it's subtype. Again, I don't think this is possible with CDI, as it's (too) strongly typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best I can do; adapting @maress

```
@Produces @CaseContext
public CaseDTO getContextCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", CaseDTO.class);
}

@Produces @CaseContext("ip")
public IPCaseDTO getContextIpCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", IPCaseDTO.class);
}

@Produces @CaseContext("group")
public GroupCaseDTO getContextGroupCase()  {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", GroupCaseDTO.class);
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD })
public @interface CaseContext {
    public String value() default "";
}
```

Then injection points

```
@Inject @CaseContext
private CaseDTO muwCase;

@Inject @CaseContext("group")
private GroupCaseDTO muwCase;

@Inject @CaseContext("ip")
private IPCaseDTO muwCase;
```

Comment: Admittedly, this still isn't that great, as I still need one producer method per-subtype...but its better than having to create a new annotation for each subtype as well

Answer (score 0):

I would do something in this respect:

```
public abstract class CaseDTO {
}
```

And the sub-class, creating a qualifier.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})
public @interface CaseContext {

    @Nonbinding
    String value() default "";

}

@ApplicationScoped
public class CaseDTOProducer {

    @ApplicationScoped
    @CaseContext("")
    public CaseDTO produce(InjectionPoint ip) {
        //You can make the instantiation as complex as you want:
        final CaseContext caseContext = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(CaseContext.class);
        switch (caseContext.value()) {
            case "ip":
                return new IpCaseDTO();
            case "group":
                return new GroupCaseDTO();
            default:
                throw new ContextException("Unknown Case Context");
        }
    }

}
```

Then the injection point:

```
public class CaseService {

    @Inject 
    @CaseContext("ip")
    private CaseDTO caseDTO;

    @Inject 
    @CaseContext("group")
    private CaseDTO caseDTO;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to put annotations on the DTO classes, they're not in a part of the project I control

Comment: @GregSt.Onge See the update using a dynamic producer.

Comment: This did work for me though, just needed to adapt the technique to my situation.

Annotation:

Comment: I think we need to ditch the 'non-binding' part of the annotation definition

Comment: If you ditch the `@Nonbinding`, then you will have to create a producer method for every value of the `CaseContext`

Comment: So, I adapted your answer into my own answer...not sure the Etiquette here...do I accept your answer?

Comment: Don't I need a producer method for every value though? Otherwise it won't match on the type? I'm pretty sure exact matches are necessary on type (ie, @Inject GroupCaseDTO will not match a producer method that returns CaseDTO, even though CaseDTO is the supertype of GroupCaseDTO)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misunderstood the [typesafe resolution mechanism](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#typesafe_resolution). The CDI injection is based on having a set of beans (in your case, producers for them) and a set of injection points (aka IP; places where you `@Inject`). Now both of these have a certain **set of types and qualifiers**.

In order to inject into IP, you need to have a bean which contains **required type** and **all requested qualifiers are a subset of qualifiers provided by the bean**.

[Bean types, in case of producers](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method_types), are derived from return type of the method. In you case it is going to be the class, every superclass and all implemented interfaces (be it directly or indirectly).

So in your code sample, if you just `@Inject CaseDTO`, you will get `Ambiguous dependency` exception - all three producers produce a bean which, *among other types*, also contains `CaseDTO`.

On the other hand, getting `Unsatisfied dependency` exception means that you have no bean which fits such injection point. In your sample, having only supertype producer means that `@Inject GroupCaseDTO` will fail with this exception because `GroupCaseDTO` is not among the types of the bean your producer creates.

As for solution to your problem - you could use qualifiers for sure. That *solves the problem of injecting supertype*. What @maress suggest in the other answer is a good idea too (e.g. no new qualifiers and use a value in the existing one)

> In fact, here's what I want: one producer method + one qualifier
>   annotation that allows me to inject the context case

You can have one qualifier giving different results, but you need to base this on some other property to know which one you want. E.g. you can have:

```
@Produces
@CaseContext
public CaseDTO produce() {
  if (methodToDetermineConfiguration()) {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", IPCaseDTO.class);
  } else {
    return JSFUtils.getFromPageFlowScope("case", GroupCaseDTO.class);
  }
}
```

Of course you need to somehow define `methodToDetermineConfiguration()` to know what you actually want to produce. Not sure what are your options there, just sharing information on how you can setup your producers.

Comment: Isn't your suggestion exactly like my first scenario that fails: including only the supertype producer?

Comment: Is CDI/WELD looking at the return type on the producer method when determining the type match?
Or is it looking that the return statements within the method? 

If it is the later, that would kinda blow my mind :)

Comment: It's not the same as your first, I was trying to explain to you how this works so you can tailor the solution to your needs based on your code. You can have one producer IFF you have some means to determine what to produce every time there is an injection. As for your second question, I suppose you didn't even bother opening the link to the docs I placed there. The very first line starts with - *The bean types of a producer method depend upon the method return type:*

Comment: No need to all condescending.                

Why would you suggest a single producer method, that returns the type CaseDTO, when you know that I want to be able to inject to a GroupCaseDTO property? Maybe you didn't read the article you linked?